# I was trying to connect the oracle 10g database with C# console application. I get error of invalid username/password even though they are right

Tags: c#, oracle10g, oledb, oledbconnection, oracle-xe

I was trying to connect the oracle 10g database with C# console application. I get error of invalid username/password even though the credentials are correct.

Here is my code:

```
string s = @"provider=MSDAORA;datasource=orcl;username=system;password=PASS";

OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection();

conn.ConnectionString = s;

conn.Open();  // Error in this line (ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied)
```

Comment: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver15 use Id and Password keyword ?

Comment: Just an aside, but Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle (MSDAORA) is depreciated (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/appendixes/microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-oracle?view=sql-server-ver15), you should use ODP.NET from Oracle.

Comment: Recently TLS1.0 and TLS 1.1 was discontinued on many servers and you must use TLS 1.2.   Old drivers will not work with TLS 1.2.  Use newer provider which supports TLS 1.2.  See : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/odpnt/install.html#GUID-1308ACD5-025A-468E-834A-CAB59FE9BB59

Comment: Thanks to everyone who responded. It turns out, i did the most embarassing mistake. I wrote username instead of user id. :):)